# RadCalendar not updating events when new event added programatically

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am using RadCalendar with Nativescript-Vue and trying to allow a user to manually (through a form) add an event but once the event gets pushed into the eventSource the calendar does not react to it (it is not shown in the view). If I re-render the Calendar, it does show the newly added event. **Any idea why the Calendar is not reacting to this change and adding the new event?**

The eventSource has a variable named calendarEvents bind to it.

```html
<RadCalendar height="100%" width="100%" ref="calendarComponent"
        id="calendar"
        :eventSource="calendarEvents"

        eventsViewMode="Inline"
        selectionMode="Single"
        viewMode="Month"
        transitionMode="Slide"

        @dateSelected="onDateSelected"
        @dateDeselected="onDateDeselected"
        @navigatedToDate="onNavigatedToDate"
        @navigatingToDateStarted="onNavigatingToDateStarted"
        @viewModeChanged="onViewModeChanged"
        @inlineEventSelected="onInlineEventSelected" />
```

And this is the method that should add the event to the calendar:

```html
    onAddBookingExternal () {
      this.$showModal(BookingExternal).then((data) => {
        if(data) {
          ...          
          let event = new calendarModule.CalendarEvent('Name', startDate, endDate, false, color)

          this.calendarEvents.push(event)
        }
      })
    },
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: is it possible for you to create a playgrond?

Comment: import { CalendarEvent } from 'nativescript-ui-calendar';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue with RadCalendar, you will have to give a new reference of array to update the UI. Just pushing data to same array doesn't trigger the update.

```
onAddBookingExternal () {
  this.$showModal(BookingExternal).then((data) => {
    if(data) {
      ...          
      let event = new calendarModule.CalendarEvent('Name', startDate, endDate, false, color)

      this.calendarEvents = [...this.calendarEvents, event];
    }
  })
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=p72PZZ)